# AjaxUpload and modified input file type doesn't work together

Tags: jquery, html, css, file-upload, ajax-upload

Starting by some nice tutorials I tried to:
1) use **jQuery** (and in particular the **AjaxUpload** library) to upload an image file from an input file button.
2) use s CSS trick to replace the default HTML5 *input file* button to a more nice custom button.
3) use HTML5 filters for allowing "only specific image" file upload.

The point is that the AjaxUpload library seems to be broken when I use the modified input file button (i.e nothing happens).

For instance, [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JqApF/) is a test with the default input file. If you try to upload a file, the loading gif say you that the file is currently in upload.
[This one](http://jsfiddle.net/qMRvG/2/) is the same with the modified input file. No loading gif is started.

Also the HTML5 file filtering seems to be broken on my Chrome browser, but it is a minor issue.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be because of some inner logic of **AjaxUpload** or security restriction of the browser. Try it with this CSS (height is 30px instead of 0%):

```
    .file-wrapper input {
         cursor: pointer;
         font-size: 100px;
         width:100%; height:30px;
         filter: alpha(opacity=1);
         -moz-opacity: 0.01;
         opacity: 0.01;
         position: absolute;
         right: 0;
         top: 0;
     }
```

Also, about accept. It must be like this (works for sure in Chrome):

```
accept="image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif,image/bmp,image/tiff"
```

And looks like it won't work with AjaxUpload. I've tried it in JSFiddle, but in result I see no accept attribute. Possibly it is removed by plugin for some reason

Comment: Yes, now it works! Thanks. However, I also have to mention that in this way it is not possible to make a customized title appear when onhover the element, so the "No file chosen" is shown by default :(. Moreover, file filtering still doesn't work! See the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qMRvG/4/)

Comment: Mhhh! I see... to be honest, also the accept=".jpg,.gif, etc." works in a separeted input file. So, seems that the AjaxUpload library is broken. I'm going to find something better!

Comment: @JeanValjean with onhover title - it must work if you put title attribute on a file input. AjaxUpload removes that one too.

Comment: Your are right! So, it is the JS library that "sucks"! There are two many drawbacks in using it. I can't rely on it. I'm going to test a new one! Thanks

Comment: and for accept - see this: [w3cschool](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp). Attribute value should be "A valid MIME type, with no parameters". I've been trying to apply accept like yours but came to what I've shown to you. As I remember, if you put mime type it works in more browsers (I guess FF does not understand file extentions in accept?)

Comment: Uh, I don't know! I use Chrome!

Comment: For the record: I moved to [Blueimp](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) and now everything works fine!